# Linux command line instructions from Java

Tags: java, linux, bash, command-line, binaryfiles

I am having a hard time figuring out how to pass command line options through Java.
My Java code needs to call a binary file which in turn runs some instructions.
The command I need to pass is

```
./program 100 -r 1
```

Now there is no way can pass the option -r 1.
In my Java code, if I run:

```
  command=new String [2];
  command[0] = ".//program";
  command[1] = " "+String.valueOf(nScen);
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

everything works fine, and program is run correctly. `nScen` is an integer. 
However, if I try

```
  command=new String [3];
  command[0] = ".//program";
  command[1] = " "+String.valueOf(nScen);
  command[2] = " -r 1";
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

or

```
  command=new String [2];
  command[0] = ".//program";
  command[1] = " "+String.valueOf(nScen)+" -r 1";
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

program does not run. I tried other things like using `.concat` instead of `+` to merge strings.
What is the correct way of doing this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't use `Runtime.exec()`, use a `ProcessBuilder` instead!

Comment: `String.valueOf(nScen)`, `-r` and `1` should probably be in separate elements in the array. (But do follow @fge's advice.)

Comment: You don't have to escape a regular /,  You only need to escape backslashes like \\.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./program  " + nScen + " -r 1");
int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
```

You'll also need to catch exceptions.

Comment: Thanks. The following worked: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./program "+nScen+" -r 1");`